# getting values from innerhtml field by php

Tags: javascript, php, html

**JS**

```
function changeFunc() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

    switch(selectedValue){
        case 'odincova':
            document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = '<select name="year"><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="2001">2001</option></select>';
            break;
        // . . . 
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <form method="post" action="congrat.php">
<tr><td id="year"></td></tr>
```

**PHP**

```
$year=$_POST['year'];
```

This doesn't work. I insert values into the table via Javascript's document.element.innerHTML, and after that I need get this values via PHP's post method, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question, could you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not good enough.  Spend some time debugging and post what you are stuck with.

Comment: Nesting a form inside `<table>` is not valid HTML. See the [permitted content for `<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). You might want to put the `<form>` inside the `<td>` or outside the `<table>`.

Comment: I have an error ///Notice: Undefined index: year

Comment: i have few rows, just rows insert by innerHTML doesnt pass the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you make the post through ajax and you add `$('#myTable .CLASS').serialize()` as data of ajax where `CLASS` is class you add to what you want serialized I think it could work

also as suggested in comments move your `<form` tag before `<table`

Comment: just move your <form tag before <table. Thank you